# Vectorizing set operations for string-valued cell arrays in MATLAB/Octave

Tags: matlab, set, octave, vectorization

I have a large data set, `X`, comprising demographic information of survey respondents. The data is largely categorical, so each row in `X` contains a bunch of string-valued features such as gender, race, interests, etc for a single respondent. Each column of `X` is a single response category. I have loaded this data set into a big cell array in MATLAB/Octave (testing on both). I would like to measure the Jaccard distance between each sample and every other sample in the data set. Basically what I want to do is this:

```
dist = zeros(size(X,1));    % Initialize my distance matrix
for ii = 1:size(X,1)
    for jj = ii:size(X,1)   % Only need the upper triangle since dist is symmetric
        % Find the Jaccard distance between the ii-th and jj-th respondent
        dist(ii,jj) = 1 - numel(intersect(X(ii,:), X(jj,:))) / numel(union(X(ii,:), X(jj,:)));
    end
end
```

Except obviously I want to vectorize the code. I have tried using `cellfun` and `bsxfun` to vectorize, but when I do something like:

```
res = cellfun('intersect', X, X, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

I get a cell array the same size as `X`, wherein the (i,j)-element is equivalent to `intersect(X(i,j), X(i,j))`; basically the unique characters in the (i-j)-cell. This does not help me. When I try:

```
res = bsxfun('intersect', X, X);
```

I get one long cell array containing (I think) all of the unique values that any cell in `X` takes. This does not help me either.

I would like a solution that enables me to vectorize the code at the beginning of this discussion. If it is easier to do so, a code that finds the subset of `X` with the minimum (or maximum) Jaccard distance from any one row in `X` would be exactly what I need.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Changed the loop code to only calculate the upper triangle of `dist`. Still takes far too long, and the fact that it is non-vectorized bugs me on a philosophical level.

**EDIT:** The first element of `X`, given by typing `X(1,:)` is:

```
ans =
{
  [1,1] = Non - U.S. Citizen
  [1,2] = Denied
  [1,3] = M
  [1,4] = CHINA
  [1,5] = Full Time
  [1,6] = D-Asian American or Pacific Islander
  [1,7] = 
  [1,8] = 
  [1,9] = MSME
  [1,10] = 
}
```

This is just testing data for developing the algorithm while I wait on my actual survey results, but the survey results will have a similar form.

**EDIT:** More data from `X`, but in CSV form, is as follows:

```
Non - U.S. Citizen,Denied,M,INDIA,Full Time,E-Other,,,MSME,
Non - U.S. Citizen,Denied,F,INDIA,Full Time,D-Asian American or Pacific Islander,,,MSME,DESIGN
Non - U.S. Citizen,Denied,M,INDIA,Full Time,E-Other,,,MS,
Non - U.S. Citizen,Denied,M,IRAN,Full Time,B-Caucasian American Non-Hispanic,,,PhD,NANO
Non - U.S. Citizen,Left Without Degree,M,JORDAN,Full Time,E-Other,,,,
Non - U.S. Citizen,Denied,F,IRAN,Full Time,E-Other,,,PhD,BIOENG
,Not Attending,M,,Full Time,,,,PhD,
Non - U.S. Citizen,Not Attending,F,IRAN,Full Time,I-International Student,,,PhD,
Non - U.S. Citizen,Denied,M,BANGLADESH,Full Time,E-Other,,,PhD,NANO
Non - U.S. Citizen,Denied,M,BANGLADESH,Full Time,E-Other,,,MS,
```

Comment: does the for loop code you posted works?

Comment: It does indeed, but it takes waaaay too long to run on a dataset that is several thousand elements long. I suppose I could half the time by only calculating the upper (or lower) triangle of the symmetric distance matrix, but that will still take hours.

Comment: can you give a small sample of X, say 10 rows long ?

Comment: Do you have the statistics toolbox? It includes a function called [`pdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html), which has an option `'jaccard'`

Comment: @Schorsch I did not know about `pdist`. I am trying to use that now, but getting the error "x must be a nonempty matrix". I assumed this meant that I could not have empty elements within `X`, so I replaced them all with `X(cellfun('isempty',X)) = 0` and I still get the same error. Does `pdist` work on string-valued vectors?

Comment: @Robocop I listed the first element of my data set as output by Octave (so you can see the cell structure), and 10 other elements from the CSV file.

Comment: what if you use `str2num` on each cell and then try `pdist` ?

Comment: @natan My strings are not string representations of numbers, they are just words. When I use `str2num` on them, I end up with an empty array as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a workaround, I'll illustrate on a single row of data:

```
a={'Non - U.S. Citizen','Denied','M','INDIA','Full Time','E-Other','','','MSME',''}
```

Sum each cell element, this casts the strings to doubles and sum thier value. It will work assuming the odds for a non unique sum result are slim (if not there's a trick you can implement, but I doubt it'll actually happen):

```
b=cellfun(@sum,a,'un',0)
```

now you have a single number per cell element, you can use `cell2mat` to get a matrix and \ or `pdist` etc ...

Comment: That got me there, but I had to change it a little. The command that ended up working (and giving me a cell array of numerals that I can convert into a matrix) was `B = cellfun('sum', cellfun('toascii', X, 'UniformOutput', false));`. I had to convert the characters in each cell to their ascii representation first, and then sum them.

Comment: instead directly taking the sum, convert to doubles and multiply each cell elements by some vector that is of the same length. This will multiply the value of each letter by some number that only depends on the position of the letter in the vector. Then sum the outcome. Now each word will be very different that any other. For example, if I have two words with the same sum, such as: 'ad' , 'bc' , now multiply with v=[1 10], and sum, you'll have sum(double('ad').*[1 10]) vs sum(double('bc').*[1 10]), and these have different sums (1097 and 1088) ...